# How fast one can calculate the compositorial?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, computational-complexity

**Definition.** The compositorial of a composite number $n$ is the product of all composite numbers up to and including $n$.

> **Question.** How fast one can calculate the [compositorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial#Applications_and_properties) $\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^n C_i$ , where $n=20000000$ ?

[PARI/GP computation](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxdzTEOwjAMQNE9p4jK4qAOZMXyFVg4QTFpsdTaletOiLsDAwtv_cM_JKV6-sLEtqy2SZjLMIMWejJVHM1_oYFQ7bVn4qMU9Ba7K3DBV1pdNKC77MutebYx32WS2M65m5tO8YBrOPwPPvANt8grMA==&lang=gp&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) gives the following results:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|} n & time \\
\hline
100000&1,007\ \rm  ms\\
200000&4,692\ \rm ms\\
300000&11,100\ \rm ms\\
400000&19,858\ \rm ms\\
500000&32,074\ \rm ms\\
\end{array}$$

Is it possible to estimate time needed for $n=20000000$ ?

**EDIT**

Using built-in PARI/GP function polinterpolate (see [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJzLszUygABrroKizLwSjYL8HCCVWgSkE0tSNaINwbI6EGU6xhDKBEKZgqlYnWhDPQMDcx0TPTNLIx1DQz1DHUNLPQtTCx1jIz0Dc5NYnTxNTWsA8IkZ2Q==&lang=gp&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==)) , I got estimated time: $93454273,148\ \rm ms$ , nearly $3$ years.

Comment: Much better to include the definition of "compositorial" than to make us chase it offsite.

Comment: How do you check for compositeness?

Comment: @Sil I am using built-in PARI/GP function: forcomposite.

Comment: @dodicta Thank you for the link.

Comment: Assuming $C_1 = 4$, so that $C_{20000000} = 21350730$, it took a little over two minutes to compute and print the number. There's certainly room for improvement. But anyway, to compute such a number quickly one needs to avoid the naive algorithm. In particular it pays to reduce the number of multiplications involving at least one large number.

Comment: @DanielFischer Are you talking about product of all composite numbers up to 21350730?

Comment: Yes, that's what I took $$\prod_{i = 1}^{n} C_i$$ to mean.

Comment: @DanielFischer How many digits has a number you got? It must be over 100000000 at least...and which programming language did you use?

Comment: 137945607 digits, I wrote a short programme in Haskell.

Comment: @DanielFischer Could you post that program as an answer? I hope I am not asking too much from you...

Comment: you could just use arithmetic progressions ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a decent algorithm and compiler, computing that number is a matter of minutes (I'm not sure if optimisation can take it to be a matter of seconds, but some tweaking can certainly make it faster than it is now). The main point to make such computations fast is to reduce the number of multiplications involving at least one large factor. Thus, instead of sequentially multiplying all the composites to an accumulator it is much faster to arrange the multiplications in a tree, so that one has one multiplication with both factors about half the size of the final result, two multiplications where both factors have about a quarter the final size, and so on.

Haskell programme (note: My GHC is old, some changes may be necessary to make it compile with newer GHCs)

```
module Compositorial where

import Data.Array.ST
import Data.Array.Unboxed
import Data.Array.Base

-- multiply all composite numbers <= n
-- Use a sieve for a fast compositeness test, and multiply in a tree-like fashion
compositorial :: Int -> Integer
compositorial n = treeProd (sieve n) 4 n

-- Sieve of Eratosthenes, basic
sieve :: Int -> UArray Int Bool
sieve end = runSTUArray (do
    ar <- newArray (0,end) False
    let mark step idx
            | idx > end = return ()
            | otherwise = unsafeWrite ar idx True >> mark step (idx+step)
        sift p
            | p*p > end = return ar
            | otherwise = do
                c <- unsafeRead ar p
                if c then return () else mark (2*p) (p*p)
                sift (p+2)
    mark 2 4
    sift 3)

-- The meat of it, tree product
-- For larger ranges, split roughly in half and recur,
-- for short ranges multiply directly
treeProd :: UArray Int Bool -> Int -> Int -> Integer
treeProd ar low high = go low high
  where
    go lo hi
        | lo + 4 < hi = let m = (hi + lo) `quot` 2 in (go lo m) * (go (m+1) hi)
        | otherwise   = product [fromIntegral n | n <- [lo .. hi], ar `unsafeAt` n]
```

This, complied with `-O2 -fllvm`, computed the compositorial of $21350730$ (since $\pi(21350730) = 1350729$, $21350730$ is the $20000000^{\text{th}}$ composite number), a number with $137945607$ digits, and printed it to a file, in

```
Total   time  114.71s  (129.96s elapsed)
```

just over two minutes.

Comment: Using this method one can speed up calculation of the factorial .

Comment: I made separated module Main :```module Main where; import Compositorial; main = do; print "Start"; putStrLn "Enter a number" ;input <- getLine; let n = (read input :: Int); print $ compositorial (n);``` , but got compiling error : ```[1 of 2] Compiling Compositorial ( Compositorial.hs, Compositorial.o ) Compositorial.hs:15:11: No instance for (MArray a0 Bool (GHC.ST.ST s)) arising from a use of ‘newArray’ The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous...``` Any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: As a first guess, the special-casing of `$` for `runSTUArray` and the like has been removed. Then replacing the `runSTUArray $ do …` with `runSTUArray (do … sift 3)` ought to work. I'll make that change in the answer, so you can see where to put the parentheses. If that still doesn't work, I'll have to dig deeper.

Comment: Same compiling error again...Is my module Main correct?

Comment: My GHC version is 7.10.3

Comment: Main module looks correct. And the compilation error occurs in the `Compositorial` module. Gotta have to dig a little, hang on.

Comment: Hmm, can't see anything relevant. Looks like type inference didn't work properly. Try adding an `import Control.Monad.ST` and replace the `ar <- newArray` line with `ar <- newArray (0,end) False :: ST s (STUArray s Int Bool)` to aid type inference.

Comment: ```[1 of 2] Compiling Compositorial    ( Compositorial.hs, Compositorial.o )

Compositorial.hs:17:9:
    Non type-variable argument
      in the constraint: MArray (STUArray s) Bool m
    (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    When checking that ‘mark’ has the inferred type
      mark :: forall (m :: * -> *).
              MArray (STUArray s) Bool m =>
              Int -> Int -> m ()
    In the first argument of ‘runSTUArray’, namely...```

Comment: Yeah, some language change occurred. I just tried on ideone and got about the same. Add `{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}` to the top (before the `module Compositorial` line). That worked on ideone with 8.4.4, should also work with 7.10.3.

Comment: Alternatively, adding type signatures to `mark` and `sift` should also work.

Comment: Message from ideone compiler: ```error: parse error on input ‘#-’```

Comment: Don't bother yourself anymore! Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I typo'ed the language pragma start. (Fixed it now.)

Comment: It works...Thank you again...